# Snackbar works only on one element of certain class

Tags: material-design-lite

I'm trying to add event listener for snackbar on all buttons with class `add-culture-button`, but it only works for the first element. For other elements, snackbar doesn't show at all (and there are no errors in console).

```
var snackbarContainer = document.querySelector("#notification");
var showSnackbarButton = document.querySelector(".add-culture-button");
var plantingLabel = document.querySelector("#planting-label");
var handler = function(event) {
    var culturesCount = parseInt(plantingLabel.attributes["data-badge"].value);
    plantingLabel.setAttribute("data-badge", culturesCount - 1);
}

showSnackbarButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var culturesCount = parseInt(plantingLabel.attributes["data-badge"].value);
    plantingLabel.setAttribute("data-badge", culturesCount + 1);
    var data = {
        message: "Kultura je dodata u listu za setvu.",
        timeout: 2000,
        actionHandler: handler,
        actionText: 'Opozovi'
    };
    snackbarContainer.MaterialSnackbar.showSnackbar(data);
});
```

Is there a way to make it work for all elements without repetition of the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I only had to use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) instead of [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)...

```
var snackbarContainer = document.querySelector("#notification");
var showSnackbarButton = document.querySelectorAll(".add-culture-button");
var plantingLabel = document.querySelector("#planting-label");
var handler = function(event) {
    var culturesCount = parseInt(plantingLabel.attributes["data-badge"].value);
    plantingLabel.setAttribute("data-badge", culturesCount - 1);
}

for (var i = 0; i < showSnackbarButton.length; i++) {
    showSnackbarButton[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        var culturesCount = parseInt(plantingLabel.attributes["data-badge"].value);
        plantingLabel.setAttribute("data-badge", culturesCount + 1);
        var data = {
            message: "Kultura je dodata u listu za setvu.",
            timeout: 2000,
            actionHandler: handler,
            actionText: 'Opozovi'
        };
        snackbarContainer.MaterialSnackbar.showSnackbar(data);
    });
}
```